# Continuar la cuenta atrás

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando crear una cuenta atrás que continúe contando aunque cierre por completo la aplicación, incluso si apago el celular.
Lo que hago es que comience a contar cuando se inicia la aplicación y cuando se cierra que guarde donde quedó, además que obtenga la hora y también la guarde.
Luego al volver a abrir la aplicación vuelvo a obtener la hora, le resto la hora almacenada anteriormente y esa diferencia, que sería el tiempo transcurrido, se le resta al valor guardado de la cuenta atrás y desde ahí continúa.

El problema es que no está funcionando como debería.

Este es mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv1;
private long Difhora1=0;
private long timeRemaining = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
    timeRemaining = preferences.getLong("PAUSED_TIME", 0);
    Difhora1 = preferences.getLong("Hora1", 0);

    Long HoraActual = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    String HAc = HoraActual.toString();

    String valor1 = HAc;
    int nro1 = Integer.parseInt(valor1);

    timeRemaining = nro1 - Difhora1;

    long millisUntilFinished = timeRemaining;

    if (millisUntilFinished <= 2000) {
        new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tv1.setText("Su imagen aparecerá en: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                tv1.setText("Listo!");
            }
        }.start();
    } else {
        new CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tv1.setText("Su imagen aparecerá en: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                tv1.setText("Listo!");
            }
        }.start();
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putLong("PAUSED_TIME", timeRemaining);
        editor.apply();

        Long HoraAnterior = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String HA = HoraAnterior.toString();

        String valor1 = HA;
        int nro1 = Integer.parseInt(valor1);

        editor.putLong("Hora1", nro1);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Antes de utilizar onStop prueba en onDestroy() que es cuando se cierra por completo la app, porque onStop() se ejecuta si tu app pasa a segundo plano y cuando vuelve a foreground pasa a onStart()

Comment: Para esto implementa un Servicio, este es un articulo en español: https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/crear-un-servicio-en-android

Comment: Hola, pero un Servicio no deja de funcionar cuando cierro por completo la aplicación o apago el celular?

Comment: Lo mejor sería que que guardes tus datos en una base de datos local (SQLite), de está forma cuando inicia guardas el dato, cierras la app y guardas el dato, al abrirla nuevamente lo registras y así consecutivamente. Además esto te llevará un registro de todas las veces que ha pasado por este escenario que nos indicas. La desventaja es que solamente la podrás utilizar mientras se mantengan los datos en la app, si deseas mantener el histórico la debes enviar a un servicio central que almacene toda la información necesaria.

Answer (score 0):

Según te he entendido quieres guardar el contador cuando la app se cierra y retomar la cuenta cuando se abre. Debes de tener en cuenta varias cosas, una cosa es que tu aplicación se vaya a background y otra que se cierre ya sea por el sistema operativo o porque el usuario la cierre y mate el proceso de la misma.

[image: Live cycle Activity]

Yo guardaría los datos en el método onPause y no en el onStop. El método onPause es llamado justo antes de que tu activity inicie el proceso de irse a segundo plano momento en el cual tu contador dejará de contar.
El método onStop es llamado después y lo normal es que transcurra un tiempo entre la llamada del onPause hasta la llamada del onStop, tiempo que no será contabilizado por tu cuenta atrás.

El inicio de la cuenta atrás yo lo movería del onCreate al onResume. El onCreate es llamado una vez cuando se crea la activity, pero no vuelve a ser llamado si esa activity está viva en memoria. Por tanto si tu aplicación se va a background y vuelve a estar activa desde ese estado no pasará por el onCreate y no iniciará de nuevo la cuenta.

Saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, el programa compila y guarda el valor de la cuenta atrás donde quedo y la retoma al iniciarlo otra vez. El problema es que no me resta el tiempo transcurrido, por ejemplo si cierro la app por  1 hs que se lo reste a la cuenta atrás al iniciar la app. Creo que algo me esta fallando cuando obtengo "Long HoraActual = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;" y trato de restarlo para continuar